# OpenGL: Draw all the scene in each iteration?

Tags: c++, opengl

I wrote some wrappers in C++ to draw some 3D points in a OpenGL scene. I'm not very experienced in OpenGL and I'm not sure if I'm following the pipeline as expected. This is more or less my code:

- Main function:

  ```cpp
  std::vector<Element> elements(1);
  while (true) {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    for (auto& element : elements) element.Draw();
    ... // some other operations and buffer swapping
  }
  ```
- `Element` class:

  ```cpp
  class Element {
   public:
     Element() {
       ... // fill m_xyz, m_rgb and m_pose
     }
     void Draw() {
       // translate
       glPushMatrix();
       glRotatef(m_pose[3], m_pose[4], m_pose[5], m_pose[6]);
       glTranslatef(m_pose[0], m_pose[1], m_pose[2]);
       // draws 3D points
       glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
       glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
       glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_xyz.data());
       glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, m_rgb.data());
       glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, m_xyz.size() / 3);
       glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
       glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
       // retrieve previous pose
       glPopMatrix();
     }
   private:
     std::vector<float> m_xyz, m_rgb, m_pose;
  };
  ```

Do I have to call `glDrawArrays` at every iteration of the main loop?

Is there any code of the `Draw` function that doesn't need to be executed all the time?

Is this how all these functions are expected to be used?

Is there a faster way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to call glDrawArrays at every iteration of the main loop?

Yes. In fact you're going to call it several times per drawing a single frame.

> Is there any code of the Draw function that doesn't need to be executed all the time?

In your code: No. Everything you have in draw belongs there.

> Is this how the all these functions are expected to be used?

Yes, for the most part.

> Is there a faster way of doing this?

Is it slow? Did you profile it?

Comment: It becomes slow (100 ms / frame) when I have around 100 elements of 250K points each. I don't know if that is good or bad performance.

Comment: 2.5MVertices/s is not *that* bad of a baseline, although modern GPUs can easily chew a couple of decadic orders of magnitude more. First things first you should check that you've got installed a proper OpenGL driver. Windows doesn't automatically install them; you'll have to download them manually from your GPU's vendor website. A bottleneck you're going through is, that the code as it is at the moment has to send the whole vertex data to the GPU for each draw call. To relieve that bottleneck you should cache your vertex data in vertex buffer objects (VBOs), thus moving it into GPU RAM.

Comment: @ChronoTrigger You may also want to confirm that you're really bottlenecked by the number of vertices when you draw more objects. It could easily be other parts of the pipeline, like fragment processing. Using GPU profiling tools is the best option if you have them available. Otherwise, a very low tech experiment is to make the window smaller. If the rendering gets faster with a smaller window, chances are that you're mostly limited by fragment processing.